# List<object> not returned from query

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have 2 calsses: a Unit class and status class. Where Unit class has a List of status. When storring data through java in my Mongodb server, every things go's fine. I tried querying it in console and everything is in there.

The problem how ever is when I use the "same" command in java, it returns all my static data but not my List. Why is that and how can I chanche it?

My Unit class:

```
@Document(collection = "unit")
public class Unit {
    @Field
    private int id;
    @Field
    private long serialNumber;
    @Field
    private String organisation;
    @Field
    private List<UnitMeasurementStatus> unitMeasurementStatusList;

    /*getters and setters */
}
```

my unitMeasurementStatus class:

```
public class UnitMeasurementStatus {
    @Field
    private Date timeStamp;
    @Field
    private int value;

    /*constructor and getters and setters */
}
```

my query in console:

```
db.unit.find({"serialNumber": 0159924843634488}).pretty()
```

my spring java code:

```
   public void findUnitByLocationId(long serialNumber) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("serialNumber").is(serialNumber));
        List<Unit> units = this.mongoTemplate.find(query, Unit.class);
    }
```

Comment: Don't see a "return" value there as well as the basic fact it's a "Cursor" and not just a ""List"

Comment: srry, updated the question, still any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you need a List you should use @DBRef

```
@DBRef
    private List<UnitMeasurementStatus> unitMeasurementStatusList;
```

[Spring Data MongoDB - Mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html)